# communicate between presenters in MVP android application

Tags: android, android-fragments, mvp

I am using MVP pattern to build a small test android app. I have two fragments Fragment B (I am using for sliding drawer) and Fragment A (main fragment). Both fragments have their own presenters. when I click on sliding draw it should send message or invoke a method in Fragment A to update view. I want to ask , how both fragments presenter can talk under MVP. I know other solutions but I want to do it through MVP pattern.

Please suggest some options that MVP pattern follows to deal such scenarios.

Comment: Hi, I am stuck in a similar situation..,how did you solve yours?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, in MVP approaches, presenter and view have 1 to 1 relation to each other. If you want to communicate between presenters using bus system like EventBus/RxBus.

I recommend following tutorial. This is a 5 part series tutorial. In this tutorial, there are two fragments (Search and Cache Fragments) communicate between each other.

https://hackernoon.com/yet-another-mvp-article-part-1-lets-get-to-know-the-project-d3fd553b3e21

Answer (score 0):

In MVP, the *View* has the `Context` to start another *View* which is either another `Fragment` or `Activity`, so any transition between your `Fragments` has to be through the *View*. In your case, you have:

View1 (Sliding Drawer Fragment) <-----> Presenter1

View2 (Main Fragment)           <-----> Presenter2

You click on a widget on View1 and want to navigate to some screen on View2 using MVP. You can do it like this:

---------------------- View 1 ---------------------

```
view1Item.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener({
    presenter1.doWhenItem1IsClicked();
}))
```

---

---------------------- Presenter 1 ----------------

```
public void doWhenItem1IsClicked(){
    mView.showRelevantPageOnMainScreen()
}
```

---

---------------------- View 1 ---------------------

```
public void showRelevantPageOnMainScreen(){
    View2 view2=new View2(); //This is better to be done using DI
 getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.your_main_page_layout,view2).commit();
}
```

---

---------------------- View 2 ---------------------

```
public void onCreate(){
super.onCreate();
presenter2=new Presenter2(this);
}
.
.
.
```

---

I have written an MVP library [here](http://www.digigene.com/mvp-easymvp-wolfkcats) you might find helpful.